# Editing multiple lines at once

Tags: python

So I need to insert about 1,000 dictionary items and I currently them in a list like:

```py
item1

item2

item3
```

and I need them to be

```
'item1',

'item2',

'item3',
```

how can I do this without manually editing 1,000 lines, thanks.

Comment: Are these items in a file?  Or do you mean they are in a code that uses a Python dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use VsCode you can user regex replace feature, you can press `ctrl+h` then activate the regex feature

[image]

Then fill the find field with `(item[\d]+)` it will find text containing `item+number`, then you replace it with `'$1',`.

`$1` means the text or pattern of first group or inside `()` symbol.

The result is:

```
'item1',
'item2',
'item3',
```

If you want to use python to do the work, you can do this:

```
import re

dictionary = '''
item1
item2
item3
'''

replaced = re.sub(r"(item[\d]+)", r"'\1',", dictionary)

print(replaced)
```